# Can you get UIPageViewController's children's layout state after animation, before actually animating?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-animation, uipageviewcontroller

So I have a `UIPageViewController` which holds two `UIViewController`. When I now set one of those `UIViewController` to be displayed by the `UIPageViewController`, the earliest I can access this `UIViewController`'s correct layout (the layout it has after being animated by the PageViewController) - as far as I know - is inside viewDidAppear.

The problem I face is that I would need to know where said ViewController's subviews **will be after the animation** before they actually animated there.

Is there any way to access that 'final state' before the animation finishes?
Or in other words, when is the earliest I can access this information?